# Flutter How to preserve the file created through getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() on iPhone?

Tags: file, flutter

I made an app for which I store input data in a file (using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()), everything works fine, except on the physical iPhone where I cannot access the data again if I quit the running app (by swiping the app after having pressed the iPhone button). Also when I reinstall the app from my code the directory changes each time (for the material iPhone). I would appreciate any help to find a solution, I'm just wondering wether I must save the dir.path using key:value.

Comment: Why don't you use packages like `SharedPreferences` or `Hive` or `LocalStorage`?

Comment: because I want to use Path_Provider ...